# How to read the property value from yaml file in springboot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my project I have a yaml file like this :
    service:
         url:http://10.10.100.09/service/ping

Currently I have setup my tests like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = 
{"service.url=http://10.10.100.09/service/ping"},webEnvironment = 
SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public abstract class BaseIntegration {

@Value("${local.server.port}")
private int serverPort;

@Before
public void setup() {
    RestAssured.port = serverPort;
}
```

}

My test are extending the BaseIntegration class and the test code reside there.

Question: How can I read the url property directly from the config file and not hardcord it in the tests?

I did try using the @SpringBootApplication annotation but its giving error when I start my tests.

Comment: do you want to read property from default `/src/main/resources/application.yml` file or from some `/src/test/resources/application-test.yml` ?

Answer (score 0):

can you try

`@SpringBootTest(properties = 
{"${service.url}"},webEnvironment = 
SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)`

or

`@SpringBootTest(properties = 
{"service.url"},webEnvironment = 
SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)`

Comment: I tried the first option and its not working. The service url is not getting read from the yaml file and my tests are failing

Comment: maybe you create application-test.yml and put the variable on it

Comment: Tried that. Now I am getting a different error of test-application.yaml file not laoding and not found in the classpath. I am using gradle . Do I need to do anything there?

Comment: not test-application.yaml , you must specify property name application-test.yml and Spring auto configure it

Comment: in addition, your application-test.yml file must be in Resorces->application-test.yml